# Angular2 JQuery, how to make the document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I could use some help in order to make the JQuery function run without any button click. Right now it only works when I have a button to click on, so the JQuery will fire.

**Code**

```
declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
selector: 'home-component',
providers: [],
moduleId: module.id,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['home.component.css'],
directives: [BannerComponent],
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public productService: ProductService, private elref: ElementRef) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): any {
        console.log("jQuery here");
        jQuery(this.elref.nativeElement).find('button').on('click', function ()          {
            jQuery('#owl-example').owlCarousel();
        });
    }

}
```

This code is ofc inside a component. It finds the button, and on click, it will run the jQuery function.

What I want is to make this line:

```
jQuery('#owl-example').owlCarousel();
```

Fire when the ngOnInit is called (without any button click). To do so I need to implement the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { }
```

The problem here is that it does not work :) What I have tried so far are this peace of code:

```
ngOnInit(): any {
    console.log("jQuery here");
    jQuery(this.elref.nativeElement).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#owl-example').owlCarousel();
    });
}
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: `jQuery('#owl-example').owlCarousel();` you should never do such things.

Comment: And why should I not do that?

Comment: Because you hardcoded CSS selector, not flexible.

Comment: You mean the Id?.. maybe I should make a class or something for all the carousels :)?

Comment: No, you should never need to use CSS selectors at all. It's the same anti-pattern as manipulating DOM in controller in Angular1. Now you component code is coupled to HTML, which is bad.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would guess that on `ngOnInit` the element with id `#owl-example` does not exists yet, because it is in the same component as where the `ngOnInit` gets called. You have to use the `ngAfterViewInit` function:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   jQuery('#owl-example').owlCarousel();
}
```

You can then be sure that any element in your component exists in the document.

Comment: works.. didn't knew you could do that.. pretty easy, thanks for your quick help.

Answer (score 4):

You can write this code within `ngAfterViewInit` hook

```
ngAfterViewInit(){    
  jQuery('#owl-example').owlCarousel();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I did it and it works!

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banners',
  templateUrl: './banners.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banners.component.css']
})
export class BannersComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   jQuery('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
}


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }

}
```